# How to access current price in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

I have the following code which uses SMA 9 crossing over SMA 200 but I want to use the current price in place of SMA 9. Is it possible to reference current price?

```
//@version=4

strategy ("Moving Average Cross", overlay=true, initial_capital=4000)

start = timestamp(2021,8,18,0,0)
end = timestamp(2021,10,18,0,0)

sma9 = sma(close,9)
sma200 = sma(close,200)
plot(sma9, title="9", color=#ff0000, linewidth=3)
plot(sma200, title="200", color=#0000ff, linewidth=3)

// Get user input
rsiSource = input(title="RSI Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
rsiLength = input(title="RSI Length", type=input.integer, defval=14)//defval is how many candles
rsiOverbought = input(title="RSI Overbought Level", type=input.integer, defval=58)
rsiOversold = input(title="RSI Oversold Level", type=input.integer, defval=35)
// Get RSI value
rsiValue = rsi(rsiSource, rsiLength)
isRsiOB = rsiValue >= rsiOverbought
isRsiOS = rsiValue <= rsiOversold
// Plot signals to chart
plotshape(isRsiOB, title="Overbought", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown, text="OB")
plotshape(isRsiOS, title="Oversold", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text="OS")

//long = sma9 > sma200
long = isRsiOS and (sma9 > sma200)
short =isRsiOB or (sma9 < sma200)

if time >= start and time <= end
    strategy.entry ("long", strategy.long, 100.0, when=long)
    strategy.close ("long", when=short)
```

Comment: Replace `sma9 = sma(close,9)` with `sma9 = close`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current price is always close. It is the closing price of the current bar which is the price now until the last update of the current candle at which time a new candle forms and the price now is still "close". In other words, close is the real time data stream.

Cheers!